# Different tolerance for parameters in klepto cache

Tags: python, memoization, klepto

I would like to set a tolerance for a certain function argument, but not for others.
Let's say I have a function like this:

```
def myFnc(input1,param0 = 0, param1 =1):
    return "input1:%s [params %s, %s]" %(input1, param0, param1)
```

These are the expected results:

```
>>>> myFnc(0.1, param0= 0.1, param1 = 1)
'input1:0.1 [params 0.1, 1]'
>>>> myFnc(0.1, param0= 0.12, param1 = 1)
'input1:0.1 [params 0.12, 1]'
>>>> myFnc(0.12, param0= 0.1, param1 = 1)
'input1:0.1 [params 0.1, 1]' #the same as the first instruction
```

I tried using tol and ignore, but I don't get what I expect:

```
>>>> from klepto import inf_cache
>>>> f=inf_cache(tol=0,ignore=("**"))(myFnc);
>>>> f(0.1, param0= 0.1, param1 = 1)
'input1:0.1 [params 0.1, 1]'
>>>> f(0.1, param0= 0.12, param1 = 1)
'input1:0.1 [params 0.1, 1]' #I wanted [params 0.12, 1] 
>>>> f(0.12, param0= 0.1, param1 = 1)
'input1:0.1 [params 0.1, 1]'
```

I am using klepto installed from pip (klepto.__version__ 0.1.1). Should I maybe change the keymap?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `klepto` author.  These look like the expected results to me.  Your line `f=inf_cache(tol=0,ignore="**")(myFnc)` tells me that you want rounding at integer tolerance, and that you want to ignore all additional `**kwds` in your function.

However, your function `myFcn` doesn't use `**kwds`, so I assume that you mean that you want to `ignore=('param0','param1')`.  When you use `ignore`, it's used to "ignore" the variables in the function declaration… not the function invocation.

When you ignore a variable, it's the **cache** that's ignoring the variable.

```
>>> f = inf_cache(tol=0, ignore=('param0','param1'))(myFnc)
>>> f(.1, param0=.1, param1=1)
(0.1, 0.1, 1)
>>> f(.1, param0=.12, param1=1)
(0.1, 0.1, 1)
>>> f(.12, param0=.1, param1=1)
(0.1, 0.1, 1)
```

Above, only `input1` (the first argument) is being cached… and it doesn't change with greater than `tol=0`.  So, when you change `param0` or `param1`… it doesn't invalidate the cache, and you still get the already-cached value returned.

So, regardless of how much you change anything other than `input1`, you will still get the originally cached value.

```
>>> f(.1, param0=5.1, param1=1)
(0.1, 0.1, 1)
>>> f(.1, param0=5.1, param1=10)
(0.1, 0.1, 1)
```

However, when I change `input1` outside of the int tolerance… then we have a second cached result.

```
>>> f(5.1, param0=5.1, param1=10)
(5.1, 5.1, 10)
```

And even if I use a `**`, the last two arguments are still ignored because the ignore applies to the function specification and not the invocation.

```
>>> f(5.1, **dict(param0=100, param1=100))
(5.1, 5.1, 10)
```

Changing the `keymap` won't change the results at all.  What changing the `keymap` does is change what is used as keys in the cache.

```
>>> f.__cache__()
null_archive({5999492624188339149: (0.1, 0.1, 1), 58251017057462798: (5.1, 5.1, 10)}, cached=True)
```

You can also see that it's using the cached values by using `lookup` instead of actually using caching.

```
>>> f.lookup(5.1, 6, 10)
(5.1, 5.1, 10)
>>> f.lookup(4.1, 5.1, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/klepto-0.1.2.dev0-py2.7.egg/klepto/_cache.py", line 341, in lookup
    return cache[keymap(*_args, **_kwds)]
KeyError: -2002243791131618159
```

Comment: Thanks for the clearer explanation of ignore mechanism! But, leaving apart the ignore keyword misunderstanding, is there a built-in way to get my "expected results" in the example, or should I resort to have a function for processing the first input (applying rounding if needed to) and then use myFnc?

Comment: I see, so you want to apply rounding, where "ignore" is used to mark which argument/keywords that you don't want to apply rounding to.  Is that correct?  The syntax in `klepto` is that `ignore` is ignoring an argument/keyword in the caching (not the rounding).  I think I have written such a function in one of my other packages (`mystic`, I believe), but you might want to try writing your own.

Comment: Ok thanks! I think I will use a helper function for checking the input then.